# Loading a package

Tags: r, forecast

When I try to load the `forecast` package in my RStudio I receive the following error. any suggestions?

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in
>   loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): 
>   there is no package called ‘xts’

Comment: `install.packages(c("xts",  "forecast"))`

Comment: Thanks John for your comment. I needed to choose no when asked do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel). library(forecast)
This is forecast 8.4 
Crossvalidated is a great place to get help on forecasting issues:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/forecasting